# Convertit valor de un int a negativo en python3.8.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer

Estoy haciendo una app en python 3.8.1 que rota las letras N(aqui el numero definido por el usuario) veces.

pero para decodificar necesito cambiar el valor del integer a negativo

por ejemplo: si el valor es 5 necesito que me lo cambie a -5

todo lo que necesite, pidalo y con gusto se lo dare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si solo quieres invertir el signo de un entero basta con anteponer el operador `-`:

> ```
> >>> a = 5
> >>> b = -a
> >>> b
> -5
>
> >>> a = -5
> >>> b = -a
> >>> b
> 5
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Lo podrías restar la cantidad 2 veces.

```
valor = 5 // ingresada por el usuario

valorSub = valor - valor

valorFinal = valorSub - valor

valorFinal (será -5)
```